# Alter datatype of clustered index primary key in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

I have a table with

```
 CONSTRAINT [user_const] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC, [group] ASC)
```

I want to change the datatype of group to NVARCHAR from NCHAR.

Simply running

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] ALTER COLUMN [group] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL;
```

gives me an error:

> The object 'user_const' is dependent on column 'group'.

`CHECK` `NOCHECK` does not work as

> This action applies only to foreign key and check constraints.

So, I thought I should drop the constraint and recreate it

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] DROP CONSTRAINT [user_const];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] ALTER COLUMN [group] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT [user_const] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC, [group] ASC)
```

But error reads

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server.

How can I alter the datatype of a column which is a primary key constraint?

Comment: **WHAT** version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you're on Azure. I think you'll have to create a new table, copy the data over, then drop the old and rename the new.

Comment: I am on running on azure sql server 12

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not support tables without clustered indexes. Read here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336245.aspx#cir

In order to change the data type, you are going to have to create a second table with the new datatypes, move the data over, and then rename.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're changing the primary key, you're effectively rebuilding the entire table anyway, so you might as well build a new table with the new format and rename to get the name right.  I haven't run this so it might need a little tweaking, but something like this:

```
-- check to see if we've already run this script and swap table names and just run it again with the old data if we have
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SysObjects WHERE name='MyTable_bak' AND type='U')
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SysObjects WHERE name='MyTable' AND type='U')
        DROP TABLE MyTable
    ELSE
        EXEC sp_rename 'MyTable', 'MyTable_bak'
GO

-- create the new table with updated columns
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    [id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [group] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC, [group] ASC
))
GO

-- copy in the data from the old version
INSERT MyTable([id],[group])
SELECT [id],[group] 
FROM MyTable_bak
GO

-- drop the old table (maybe wait to do this until testing is complete?)
DROP TABLE MyTable_bak
```